# Atomic enveloping von Neumann algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. If the second dual of $A$, which is the enveloping von Neumann algebra of $A$, is atomic, can we deduce that $A$ is an ideal in its second dual ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $A$ to be $c$, the space of convergent sequences.  Its second dual is $l^\infty$, which is atomic, but it is not an ideal of $l^\infty$.

Comment: Or more generally, let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space which is countable infinite.  Then `$C(K)^*=\ell^1(K)$` and so `$C(K)^{**}=\ell^\infty(K)$`, but $C(K)$ is unital, so won't be an ideal in its bidual.